# Fibonacci sequence without for loop in octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to create a Fibonacci sequence without for loop in octave, but all I get is error and I'm totally stuck here. Any ideas on how to deal with this

```
x(1)=1;
x(2)=1;
m=3:10
x(m)=x(m-1)+x(m-2)
```

> *error: x(9): out of bound 2 (dimensions are 1x2)*

I was expecting getting the 1st 10 Fibonacci sequence but it isn't working

Comment: You've only defined what `x(1)` and `x(2)` are, so when you do `x(m-1)` if `m-1` > 2, your code will fail since this value is not defined. You basically have 3 choices: 1. Use a for loop. 2. Use a recursion. 3. Avoid the loop/recursion and use a closed-form expression:  `F(n) = (φ^n - (-φ)^-n) / √5`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Octave does not recalculate in-place vectorized operators at each step (nor MATLAB, as far as I'm aware of), so

```
octave> x=ones(1,10)
x =
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

octave> x(3:10)=x(2:9)+x(1:8)
x =
    1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

You can either use a closed-form expression, as mentioned on the comments, or just do a simple loop:

```
octave> x=ones(1,2)
octave> for i=3:10
> x(i)=x(i-1)+x(i-2)
> endfor
```